# How to pass Views between Classes

Tags: android

I've been working on android for few months, during my spare time, so probably i'm going to ask stupid questions.

In a class, I create an object, for example a button, and I'd like to 'reach' it from others classes.

Of course i could do it this way:

```
public class CreateButton{

      public void createButton(){

         Button myButton = new Button(context);         

        //I can "pass" my object to another class this way
        ManageButton manageButton = new ManageButton(myButton);

        // or this way
        manageButton.writeButtonTextMethod(myButton); 

     }
}
```

or this way

```
public class CreateButton{

      public Button createButton(){

        Button myButton = new Button(context);
        return myButton;

      }

}


public class ManageButton{

      public void writeButtonTextMethod(){

        CreateButton createButton = new CreateButton()     
        Button myButton = createButton.createButton();
        myButton.setText("W"); 

      }   
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to 'reach' myButton, created in **createButton.class** directly from **ManageButton.class** (and other classes).

With the code above, I have to 'call' **createButton.class**  from  **ManageButton.class** or vice versa to be allowed to manage myButton.

I can do it making myButton **static**, but it's not correct make view static.

For example, i can easily reach variables created in a class that extends **Application**. Is there something similar for views?

Comment: Why do you want to share `View`s among Activities?

Comment: Question of 10000 crores **Why do you want to share View**?

Comment: No sorry, not between activities, but between classes.
In one of my class, I create an array of buttons, and i would like to reach this array from other classes, without passing the array in classes constructor each time.

Comment: Sorry mate, but I can't help more than I wrote down in last edit. Hope u will find acceptable one of given advices (and accept the answer ;)) Cheers and good luck in a learning process.. Hope u will enjoy it

Answer (score 2):

> Much people/guides/articles claim is possible and correct sharing objects (and fields) between activities by using Application, this way:

Such people are idiots, as `myButton` will introduce a memory leak unless this is done very carefully.

> So, I'm still not sure how i should share objects (TextView, Button, ImgaeView etc.) among different activities.

You don't share widgets between activities. At most, you share model data between activities (or, better yet, pointers to centrally-stored model data).

In a Web app, you do not share DOM nodes between Web pages, as that is not possible. At most, you share data passed as GET parameters and the like between Web pages, or you store data in local central storage (cookies, local storage, IndexedDB, etc.). Android activities are like Web pages -- they are loosely coupled.

If you have pieces of your UI that are *so* tightly coupled that they absolutely *need* to share widgets, they should not be separate activities.

Comment: No sorry, not between activities, but between classes.
In one of my class, I create an array of buttons, and i would like to reach this array from other classes, without passing the array in classes constructor each time.

Comment: @MatteoDepasquali: This is rudimentary Java programming. Use setters on the "other classes". Or, pass the `Activity` in the constructor and use getters on the `Activity` to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

Views are not meant to be shared across Activities. Even if you do disregard this and share them, you're more than likely to run into a `WindowManager$BadTokenException`, which essentially means you can't alter Views outside of its parent Activity.

However, to answer your question in a more general way about sharing non-view objects, the Application class is the right way to go. However, making the objects static is not the right way to do. Instead, make them instance variables, and access them in in your various activities by using:

```
Application application:

//Below line is in onCreate()
application = this.getApplication();
```

After that, simple access it using

```
application.myObject; //Or you could use getters and setters. Your choice.
```

Comment: No sorry, not between activities, but between classes.
In one of my class, I create an array of buttons, and i would like to reach this array from other classes, without passing the array in classes constructor each time.

Comment: Again, why are you passing Views? Views should be access **only** from their Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure why would u like to share one button between two activities?!
It is either button in ActivityA or ActivityB? No need, or use to do it..You shouldn't do it.

**EDIT:** This is more **Java Basics topic** then Android.. And from what I understood, u call "class" something that IMHO is method (because u can't CALL the class and because what did you described).

***Best advices I can give u here:***

1. *Study Java basics (methods, classes, objects, constructors, inheritance..)*,
2. *Study Android basics (simple examples with 1 activity til u understand it good)*,
3. *Make MyButton Class which will extend standard button*,
4. *Create button(s) and change their properties*

***This few tasks will make u busy for some time. Take it easy because it will be easier later with complicated apps.*** Hope I helped you. Cheers

**EDIT2:** In last example u wrote (in comments to this answer), nothing make sense because as we wrote u before u don't share button between two activities. Pause! *Read it again:* **You should't share button between two Activies**. Questions u asked are not clear because for A and Z u can't say just class and "share" button between them. Which class? no line of code written so it is really difficult to figure out what u want.. :s

**LAST LAST EDIT:** Man.. Please understand that u r missing basics of Java. No bad intentions here, just try to guide u and tell u exactly what u should study. Why? Because it doesn't surprise me that you are confused to explain what u mean when classes are with one method named exactly the same.. They are just objects "doing something", u want to "manage" them by adding variable in constructor which doesn't exist etc.. Learn, next time write immediately code to save time for all of us. Cheers and enjoy learning

Comment: No sorry, not between activities, but between classes.
In one of my class, I create an array of buttons, and i would like to reach this array from other classes, without passing the array in classes constructor each time.

Comment: Now we are coming to the field of Java basics.. And still widgets like buttons should be related just to activities or fragments they exist in.. Anyway to understand everything better, maybe u would like to edit ur question anddescribe in details use case u have "troubles" with and give us a piece of code u already used to accomplish descibed situation

Comment: I called them classes to make it easier. Of course i was talking about methods created inside those classes :D Maybe I couldn't explain it well. I try to make the question easier. I create an object, for example a button, in class A  and I want to "manage" that object in class Z. 
In class A I could do `Z classZ = new Z(button_I_want_to manage)`
But, i can do it, only if I create an object of class Z inside class A. I was wondering if there's a way to reach, from class Z, an object created in class A, in a situation in which in class A I don't create an object of class Z

Comment: I want to help mate, but I got impression u r not super sure what is what.. A bit unsure about what is what in Java, and a lot not sure what is what in Android. Please trust me and listen to advice in my edited answer (Java, OOP, Inheritance / Android, Activities, lifecycle, Views) and after some time figuring that out u will realize that what u asked doesn't make sence..

Comment: Thank you man for helping me, you are very kind. Probably i used the wrong words when asking my question. Actually i don't want to 'share' object. Anyway i edited my question and wrote a little code, so, i hope, you can understand what i meant (provided you have time to waste to read it) :)